# Is `for` a function in R?

Tags: r

At *page* 307 of Norman Matloff's *The Art of R Programming*, the author says

> `for()` is, in fact, a function.

The context is to give a remark on a piece of code snippet

```
for (i in 1:length(x)) z[i] <- x[i] + y[i]
```

The author comments

> Though syntactically the loop looks innocuous, `for()` is, in fact, a
>   function.

My understanding is that what he is saying is that `for()` is a function much like `+` is a function (callable object). Say we may call `+` in a standard function calling way like

```
"+"(3 ,5)  # 8
```

I have background in C/C++ and Python and I have noticed several subtle differences between the languages. For example,

- `return` is a function, not a statement, in R, so that we must write `return(1)` with the parentheses.

Going back to my question: is `for` a function in R?

Thanks for any clarification.

Comment: `for` is written in C. Might be worth looking at its source code to understand why. Might not be a very trivial task.

Comment: Everything is a function in R

Comment: R is a functional programming language. This [article](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html) might be a good read

Comment: Many thanks for the above comments. Previously I've been focusing on *using* R, whereas recently I am turning to *understanding* R.

Comment: I think that [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Control.html) you may find an answer to your question.

Comment: I just noticed that calling `is.function(\`for\`)` and `is.primitive(\`for\`)` work and show that R, if asked, considers `for` as a primitive function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`for` is a function, but the symbol `for` is also recognised by the parser as part of the convenient syntax that we can use to call the function `for`. These are two different things conveniently named the same (note that `in` is not a function).

```r
is.function(`for`)
#> [1] TRUE

x <- y <- z <- 1:3
for (i in 1:length(x)) z[i] <- x[i] + y[i]
z
#> [1] 2 4 6

x <- y <- z <- 1:3
`for`(i, 1:length(x), z[i] <- x[i] + y[i])
z
#> [1] 2 4 6
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

In a similar fashion the `if (cond) foo else bar` syntax maps to the function call `` `if`(cond, foo, bar) ``, but there is no `else` function.

All other control flow constructs (see `?Control`) are also functions.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation.